# Dependency Injection / Polymorphism in Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c, dependency-injection, polymorphism

Can I use Objective C `protocols` the same way I would use Java `interfaces` for Dependency Injection or Polymorphism?

It seems like I cannot. Note that in (1) below I have to ***type*** the property as the implementation rather than as the protocol. I get a compiler error if I use the protocol as the `property` type.

**(1) The object to have dependencies injected into:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FOO_AccountService.h"
#import "FOO_BasicAccountService.h"

@interface FOO_ServiceManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) FOO_BasicAccountService <FOO_AccountService> *accountService;

...

@end
```

**(2) The protocol:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FOO_Service.h"

@protocol FOO_AccountService <FOO_Service>

...

@end
```

**(3) The implementation:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FOO_BasicService.h"
#import "FOO_AccountService.h"

@interface FOO_BasicAccountService : FOO_BasicService <FOO_AccountService>

...    

@end
```

Comment: Downvotes without comments are crazy unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<FOO_AccountService> accountService;
```

Now your property will work with any object type that conforms to the `FOO_AccountService` protocol.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure what the id keyword was for. Now I know.